# How to embed a third party popup button script in React/NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, embed

I have a NextJS site powered by Wordpress.
I have a button code a user puts in a textbox in WP then when Next builds the site it displays the code.

The issue I am having is my button appears but when a user clicks the button nothing happens.

The button code

```
<button class='flybook-book-now-button fb-widget-type-frontend fb-default-category-id-0 fb-account-id-687 fb-entity-config-id-15549 fb-domain-go.theflybook.com fb-protocol-https' style='background-color: #ee5505;'>BOOK NOW</button><link rel='stylesheet' href='https://go.theflybook.com/content/bootstrapper/flybookbootstrap.css' /><script src='https://go.theflybook.com/custom/bootstrapper/flybookbootstrap.js'></script>
```

And im my component I render the filed using 'dangerously-set-html-content' like this

```
          <>
            {title && <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>}
            {subheader && <h3 className={styles.subheader}>{subheader}</h3>}
            {body && <p className={styles.body}>{body}</p>}
            <InnerHTML html={buttonCode} />
          </>
```

This will display the button but then when i click it i should get a pop up but nothing happens.

Looking for a solution for this, i need to do about 6 on each page.....

Comment: So you're saying there's an issue with the third-party button? Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the third-party code that gets loaded along with the button.

Comment: Got it, just needed to use <Link> around it and edit the code it gave me a bit.